# Which ssh exploit works by changing the user name in the middle of the process?

Tags: ssh, known-vulnerabilities, openssh, log-analysis

Every few hours, I get a few of those in my server logs:

```
sshd[...]: Disconnecting: Change of username or service not allowed: (httpd,ssh-connection) -> (http,ssh-connection) [preauth]
sshd[...]: Disconnecting: Change of username or service not allowed: (identd,ssh-connection) -> (ident,ssh-connection) [preauth]
sshd[...]: Disconnecting: Change of username or service not allowed: (administrator,ssh-connection) -> (admin,ssh-connection) [preauth]
sshd[...]: Disconnecting: Change of username or service not allowed: (admins,ssh-connection) -> (admin,ssh-connection) [preauth]
sshd[...]: Disconnecting: Change of username or service not allowed: (admissions,ssh-connection) -> (adm,ssh-connection) [preauth]

...other attempts of the same kind: tony -> to, users -> user, wwwrun -> www, ...
```

Apparently, someone tries to confuse my ssh daemon by first identifying himself as `foo` and then as `somePrefixOfFoo` (without success, obviously).

Is or was there some specific vulnerability in SSH which would allow such an attack to succeed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think, there was any vulnerability in this, at least not in `openssh`. The code resulting in this error was added in [this commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/9d0c06667eb4ca616ffa690e88b9dd7c438e3103) and it is referencing recommendation from `ietf-drafts`. Probably [RFC4252](http://www.openssh.com/txt/rfc4252.txt), which states today:

> The 'user name' and 'service name' are repeated in every new
>   authentication attempt, and MAY change.  The server implementation
>   MUST carefully check them in every message, and MUST flush any
>   accumulated authentication states if they change. **If it is unable to
>   flush an authentication state, it MUST disconnect if the 'user name'
>   or 'service name' changes.**

So I believe it is the highlighted case.